How to disable -Werror in building AOSP
How would I disable the -Werror flag or add -Wno-error flag to AOSP/LineageOS? I'm trying to build a kernel for my specific device and it built fine on its own, but once added to the source tree, it doesn't build and throws a lot of errors.
I tried building with brunch a06 but it threw random errors that didn't appear when it was built by itself.

One way is to check the Environment Variables: Sometimes, the build system uses environment variables for flag. You can temporarily disable warnings being treated as errors by running:
export DISABLE_WERROR=true

This may not work in all cases but can help if AOSP/LineageOS uses such environment variables for configuration.

That seemed to do it, thank you!
